# Multiline label with UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to use a component created with UIKit in SwiftUI by using `UIViewRepresentable`. The result I want to achieve is to have a textfield on top of my view and my UIKit view stacked at the bottom with an automatic height.

The problem is this component includes a multiline label and from what I see it makes it really hard to have an automatic height working properly, so my UIKit component takes all the available space in my VStack.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJMeN.png)
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7khj.png)

Here is my code included in a playground to test it. I tried to play with hugging priorities but nothing worked for me, and if I test with a swift UI view it works correctly.. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class InformationView: UIView {
    lazy var label = UILabel()
    lazy var button = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(button)

        label.text = "zaeiof azoeinf aozienf oaizenf oazeinf oaziefj oazeijf oaziejf aozijf oaizje foazeafjoj"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.setTitle("My button title", for: .normal)
        button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

        addConstraints([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct InformationRepresenter: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> InformationView {
        let view = InformationView(frame: .zero)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: InformationView, context: Context) {

    }
}

struct Info: View {
    var body: some View {
        return HStack {
            Text("zaeiof azoeinf aozienf oaizenf oazeinf oaziefj oazeijf oaziejf aozijf oaizje foazeafjoj")

            Button("My button title", action: {
                print("test")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Field", text: $text)
                .padding()

            Spacer()

            // SwiftUI works
            // Info().background(Color.red).padding()

            // UIViewRepresentable doesn't
            InformationRepresenter().padding()
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().frame(width: 400, height: 800, alignment: .top))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.

- `InformationView` doesn't have an `intrinsicContentSize`. SwiftUI relies on this property to determine a `UIView`'s ideal size.
- No `fixedSize` modifier. This modifier forces a view to maintain its ideal size rather than grow to fill its parent.

You can't add an `intrinsicContentSize` because the content size is dynamic; it's based on the number of lines in your label.

You can't add the `fixedSize` modifier, because without an `intrinsicContentSize`, this will set the size to (0,0).

One solution is to wrap `InformationView` in a `UIView` that measures the `InformationView` size, and updates its own `intrinsicContentSize` according to that measurement.

Your `InformationView` should fill the width of the screen; it doesn't have an intrinsic width. On the other hand, the intrinsic height should be equal to the height of the [compressed system layout size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefitting). This is "the optimal size of the view based on its constraints".

Here is the wrapper:

```swift
class IntrinsicHeightView<ContentView: UIView>: UIView {
  var contentView: ContentView

  init(contentView: ContentView) {
    self.contentView = contentView
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    backgroundColor = .clear
    addSubview(contentView)
  }

  @available(*, unavailable) required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  private var contentHeight: CGFloat = .zero {
    didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
  }

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    .init(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentHeight)
  }

  override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
      guard frame != oldValue else { return }

      contentView.frame = self.bounds
      contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

      let targetSize = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height)

      contentHeight = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        targetSize,
        withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
        verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel).height
    }
  }
}
```

This `IntrinsicHeightView` is a generic `UIView` that, when its frame changes, recalculates the height of its `intrinsicContentSize` according to the compressed system layout height of its content view.

Here is the update to `InformationRepresenter`:

```swift
struct InformationRepresenter: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> IntrinsicHeightView<InformationView> {
        return IntrinsicHeightView(contentView: InformationView())
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: IntrinsicHeightView<InformationView>, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

And finally, when using it in SwiftUI:

```swift
InformationRepresenter()
  .padding()
  .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Using the `fixedSize` modifier this way allows the `UIView` to fill the parent, but use `intrinsicContentSize.height` as its height. Here is the  [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35RLr.png). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it really helped me understand what was the root issue and how to solve it  To be honest I initially thought that UIViewRepresentable would be more "plug and play" for a view that looks quiet simple!

Comment: Brilliant! If you break out the code inside frame into a separate function and call the new function in updateUIView(...) it will also resize correctly when the content changes during run time.

Comment: This turned out to be the best way to use a UILabel in SwiftUI. All other solutions had bugs and weird edge cases